# I don't hold anyone's ambitions against them senator?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language

[Post-credits scene from Mafia III](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KXKZ1IPnOs4)

> I don't hold anyone's ambitions against them, Senator! And you were certainly ambitious weren't you?

What does Mr. Donovan mean by these sentences ? What kind of ambition is being "used" heree

Also please watch the whole video ! This scene is little bit complex

Comment: The regular kind. to hold something against someone is an  idiom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context of the phrase "I don't hold anyone's ambitions against them", holding against is an idiom. It essentially means to think of someone badly because of something they have or did. 
[Here it is on dictionary.com for reference.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hold-against)